# Union lets me access members that are not common to all types

Tags: typescript

I'm either misunderstanding union types in TypeScript, or the documentation is incorrect. In the [advanced types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) section, it says with the following example:

> If we have a value that has a union type, we can only access members
>   that are common to all types in the union.
>
> ```
> interface Bird {
>     fly();
>     layEggs();
> }
>
> interface Fish {
>     swim();
>     layEggs();
> }
>
> function getSmallPet(): Fish | Bird {
>     // ...
> }
>
> let pet = getSmallPet();
> pet.layEggs(); // okay
> pet.swim();    // errors
> ```

However, in my current TypeScript project, I seem to be doing exactly what it says I can't. I created a type (`FilterAction`) that is a union type composed of two other types, `FilterByReportType` and `FilterByTag`:

```
export type FilterAction = FilterByReportType | FilterByTag | FilterByCoffeeFlavour  

export interface FilterByType {
    type: constants.FILTER_BY_TYPE;
    report_type: string;
}
export interface FilterByTag {
    type: constants.FILTER_BY_TAG;
    tag: string;
}
 export interface FilterByCoffeeFlavour {
    type: constants.FILTER_BY_COFFEE_FLAVOUR;
    coffeeFlavour: string;
}
```

The `action` (as it's called) gets passed to a function that switches on the type, and then (and this is the surprising part) it's able to access the member that is not common to all the types in the union.

```
function filters(state: Filter = initialState, action: FilterAction) : Filter {
  switch (action.type) {
    case c.FILTER_BY_TAG:
       return Object.assign({}, state, { filterType: "tag", secondaryFilter: action.tag}) //accessing the uncommon member here w/o problem
    case c.FILTER_BY_REPORT_TYPE:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { filterType: action.report_type, secondaryFilter: ""})
   case c.FILTER_BY_COFFEE_FLAVOUR:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { filterType: action.coffeeFlavour, secondaryFilter: ""})
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Furthermore, if, for example,when I switch on `FILTER_BY_TAG`, and try to access a member from one of the other types (such as `coffeeFlavour`), then TypeScript (rightly) complains that `coffeeFlavour` doesn't exist on  FilterByTag, which further reinforces that my union is working as I hoped.

Why in this situation am I able to access members that are not common to all types of the union, or, conversely, how does my use case not come into the scope of unions described in the documentation?

Comment: It *is* in the scope of unions described in the docs - by `switch`ing on something that distinguishes the individual types, you create a [**discriminated union**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions). Within each `case`, you know (and, more importantly, *the TypeScript compiler knows*) it's the more specific type.

Comment: I was about to answer the question but I did not know the typescript term for _"smart casting"_. +1 @jonrsharpe

Comment: @jonsharpe ok, thank you.  What you're saying and what it says in the documentation is entirely different, though, unless there's expanded docs.  ` If we have a value that has a union type, we can only access members that are common to all types in the union.`

Comment: @Leahcim it's not entirely different, the link above is *to* the same documentation. You can only access common members *where you don't know which specific member type you have*; given that you've explicitly branched your code on that, each branch has more information. If you take the page as a whole, it covers lots of cases where you can be more specific, e.g. the type guards that immediately follow the section you quote. It gives the general rule, then discusses the various exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the line where you want an error to happen but isn't happening:

```
return Object.assign({}, state, { filterType: "tag", secondaryFilter: action.tag}) //accessing the uncommon member here w/o problem
```

The reason why its not happening : Because it is under `case c.FILTER_BY_TAG:` This tells TypeScript the *type* and thanks to TypeScript's flow analysis it knows that `action` is of type `FilterByTag` and no longer `FilterAction`.

## More

Discriminated unions in TypeScript : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/discriminated-unions.html

Comment: I thought it had to have a "kind" property to be a discriminated union